# Objective C Syntax - Internal Browser

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'm looking for a bit of advice in objective c syntax, as I think that's were I am going wrong here.

I have the following code, which determines the hyperlinks etc of a few links in the sidebar.

```
 switch (indexPath.row)
    {
        case 0:
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotificationName:@"showDiscoverPage" object:nil];
            break;
        case 1:
            mail = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"mailto://%@",[config getMail]];
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:mail]];
            break;
        case 2:
             [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[config getWebSite]]];
            break;
default:
            break;
    }
```

However, I want some links to open in an internal browser. I am using https://github.com/TransitApp/SVWebViewController

I was thinking that the syntax would be as follows:

```
 webViewController = [[SVWebViewController alloc] initWithAddress:[config getTwitter]];
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:webViewController animated:YES];
```

...and adding this before the switch

```
SVWebViewController *webViewController;
    switch (indexPath.row)
```

It doesn't throw any errors but it just doesn't do anything when clicked. Any advice?

I got it to work with all links within a web view by doing the following:

```
-(BOOL) webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)inRequest navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    if ( navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked ) {
        SVModalWebViewController *newWebViewController = [[SVModalWebViewController alloc] initWithAddress:[[inRequest URL] absoluteString]];
        [self presentViewController:newWebViewController animated:YES completion:NULL];
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

P.S I am a complete beginner.

Comment: Do you have a `navigationController`?

Comment: yeh i just added where i got it to work elsewhere by using the following code

Comment: Aside: this is not a question about syntax. Syntax is the set of rules that tell you how to form valid expressions. Your question relates to how to use the frameworks provided to accomplish your goal, i.e. what to say, now how to say it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using a `UINavigationController`, so when you try to push the web view controller:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:webViewController animated:YES];
```

`self.navigationController` is nil and thus the message goes nowhere.

On the other hand, you use a different presentation mechanism for your `UIWebView`:

```
[self presentViewController:newWebViewController animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

which does not rely on a navigation controller being there.
You can use the same mechanism with your `SVWebViewController`:

```
webViewController = [[SVWebViewController alloc] initWithAddress:[config getTwitter]];
[self presentViewController: webViewController animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

and it will work. This is a fine solution, provided you do need any navigation across your controllers, otherwise you will have to add a navigation controller to your UI.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Storyboard, click in your ViewController that you want to push the web view, go to `Editor / Embed in / Navigation Controller`, and try again (it should work).